# Is the URL not available across feature files anymore?

Tags: karate

Is the URL not available across feature files anymore?
As example, in our main feature files we would set the background as such:

Background:

```
* url url
* header Authorization = token
* def baseUrl = 'care/v1.1/account/'
```

Where the url is coming from our javascript config file.  We have multiple environments we run our Karate suite on, and have config files that point to each of them, therefore the url is unique per environment.  Then in the required scenarios there would be a call to a "helper" feature file.  Inside that feature file there would be no background and only 1 scenario.  That scenario would look like:

```
        * path baseUrl
 Given path 'MTYzODJAQDg=/call/add'
```

That would work fine with Karate 1.20.  Now on Karate 1.3.0.RC2 that setup is failing.  It's like the url variable is not being shared or something with the helper feature files.  The scenarios that call helper feature files will now fail.

I've been able to "fix this", by adding the same url declaration that is in the main feature files, to our helper feature files, essentially so all feature files have it.

My question is, is this now the expected behaviour in the new version.

Comment: it is funny that people are complaining about the opposite of what you want here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2054

Comment: I guess that's why you get into customization, so people can have it function multiple ways.  I'm not saying Karate should work one way or another, this is the way we had been using it without issue.  If this is how Karate is going to work moving forward, so be it.  This is why I test RCs, so we can see if anything breaks.  What I don't like, is in ticket it says "I thought programming languages generally completely separate called function's scope from their parent except for explicitly passed through inputs", and I was under the impression Karate is not a programming language

Comment: first, I'm really sorry that behavior which I consider a bug in karate was depended on by you. in my defense, no where in the documentation or demos did I give examples of such usage. everyone has opinions on what programming languages should or should not do. is karate a programming language ? I leave it to you :) no further comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the url declaration (* url url) to the "helper" feature files, essentially having it in every feature file, will "fix" the "problem".

Comment: here's my 2c: this is not a "problem" this is normal usage of a variable because you want the actual URL to change. very standard stuff.

Comment: Perhaps we are just url and path wrong.  We don't want url to change, ever.  The path may or may not change.  For us, url comes from the config file, and will be environment specific, so it will be "http://somenvironment:someport/nsbl" and then the path will be "/path1/" in some places, in others it will be "/path2/".  So with 1.2.0 we would declare url in the background of the main feature and not require it in helper feature, now we do.  At the end of day that isn't a big deal, just a change from current behaviour, which is why we test RCs.  Thanks again for info, it's much appreciated!

Comment: you do know that you can use variables for `path` right ? have you tried `* path someVariable` - and if `someVariable` is null, it will do nothing. which may be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

First, `path` is not a "variable" and it is [NOT designed to work when you `call` anything](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1990#issuecomment-1175783697).

I have 2 suggestions.

1. Set your environment-specific config in `karate-config.js`. That is what it is designed for, and you can very well call a feature to do it. See [`karate.callSingle()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#hooks).
2. Use variables to "pass around" information which "called" features can use. Or when you make a `call`, you can "return" values that can be used by subsequent steps.

I think that trying to use a "call" instead of pre-setting variables is the source of your troubles. If you need to switch the `url` when you call something, just use a variable.

EDIT: Karate now has a solution for this specific ask: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2209